# Remove Integers and special characters from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to python, would like to remove special characters and integers from column values. I do want to remain with only string characters in the column. For this case is *column C* that I do want to remove special characters like those slashes and numerics,
see table

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'A':['NW', 'NB', 'UK', 'CAN', 'der'],'B':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','mark'], 'C':['|20|Empty,', 'Yes| -1', 'Male|-1|2-female|0', 'Yes| 1', 79]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)
```

Now if a row has only an integer in column C, I should delete it, I have tried this which doesnt work well

```
df['C'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\-,+', '', x))
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'A':['NW', 'NB', 'UK', 'CAN'],'B':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'C':['Empty', 'Yes', 'Male female', 'Yes']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) + [str.strip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and finally [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df['C'] = df.C.str.replace('(?i)[^a-z]', ' ').str.replace('\s+', ' ').str.strip()
print(df.dropna())
```

**Output**

```
     A      B            C
0   NW    Tom        Empty
1   NB   nick          Yes
2   UK  krish  Male female
3  CAN   jack          Yes
```

Comment: `df['C'] = df.C.str.replace('[^a-z]', ' ', case=False).str.replace('\s+', ' ').str.strip()` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.replace`

**Ex:**

```
data = {'A':['NW', 'NB', 'UK', 'CAN', 'der'],'B':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','mark'], 'C':['|20|Empty,', 'Yes| -1', 'Male|-1|2-female|0', 'Yes| 1', 79]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["C"] = df["C"].str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", regex=True).str.strip() 
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     A      B            C
0   NW    Tom        Empty
1   NB   nick          Yes
2   UK  krish  Male female
3  CAN   jack          Yes
4  der   mark          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `.apply`

```
>>> df['C'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]+', ' ', str(x)))
0         Empty
1          Yes 
2    Male female
3          Yes 
4              
Name: C, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work, but might not be the optimal way of doing it.

```
df["C"].str.replace("[0-9]","").str.replace("|"," ").str.replace(",","").str.replace("-","").dropna()
```